# Data scraped from amazon returns empty list ? scraping deals of the day in amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

**This is the function of getting deals**

```
def scrape_amazon_deals():
    # Make a request to the Amazon Deals page
    HEADERS = ("--------my header----")
    response = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS)

    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the deal elements on the page
    deal_elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a-image-container a-dynamic-image-container aok-align-center-horizontally'})

    # Prepare a list to store the deal details
    deals = []

    # Extract the required details from the deal elements
    for deal_element in deal_elements:
        title = deal_element.find('span', {'class': 'a-text-normal'}).text.strip()
        original_price = deal_element.find('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'}).text.strip()
        deal_price = deal_element.find('span', {'class': 'a-price'}).find('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'}).text.strip()
        product_url = 'https://www.amazon.com' + deal_element.find('a')['href']
        image_url = deal_element.find('img', {'class': 's-image'})['src']
        deals.append({'title': title, 'original_price': original_price, 'deal_price': deal_price, 'product_url': product_url, 'image_url': image_url})

    return deals
```

**output is empty list**

```
[]
```

## I want to create a function to get all products in deals of the day of amazon

**I also used user agent and also proxies to gain access but nothing works**

## expecting :-

**want the list of dictionaries where every dictionary represent one product details (upto 1000 product deals only!)**

```
[
 { productname : 'wrjnjnr',
   productorgprice : 123,
   productdealprice : 244,
   productpurchaselink : https://hogj3i3oir0i/,
   productimageurl : https://4hfjkb2orih/,
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements you want doesnt match your find_all query, the string you posted is substring of the class element you want

Change your code

```
deal_elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'a-image-container a-dynamic-image-container aok-align-center-horizontally'})
```

To this

```
deal_elements = soup.select('div[class*="a-image-container a-dynamic-image-container aok-align-center-horizontally"]')
```

Comment: didnt worked bro. returned same empty list

Comment: Then check the html and lookup for your elements

Comment: Do your get "<Response [503]>" on response??

Comment: nope got 200 response everything is good